# How to slow down or set given speed on the Kafka stream consumer?

Tags: performance, queue, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to control number of messages which are consumed by the KStream and I am not very succesful.

I am using: 
`max.poll.interval.ms=100`
and
`max.poll.records=20`
to get like 200 messages per second.

But it seems to be not very good, as I see that there are like 500 messages per second also in my statistics.

What else shall I set on the side of the stream consumer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I am using: max.poll.interval.ms=100 and max.poll.records=20 to get
>   like 200 messages per second.

max.poll.interval.ms and max.poll.records properties do not work this way.

**max.poll.interval.ms** indicates the maximum time interval in milliseconds the consumer has to wait in between each consumer poll of the topic.

**max.poll.records** indicates the maximum number of records the consumer can consume during each consumer poll of the topic.

The interval between each poll is not controlled by the above two properties but by the time taken by your consumer to acknowledge the fetched records.

For example, let's say a topic X exists with 1000 records in it, and the time taken by the consumer to acknowledge the fetched records is 20ms. With max.poll.interval.ms = 100 and max.poll.records = 20, the consumer will poll the Kafka topic every 20ms and in every poll, max of 20 records will be fetched. In case, the time taken to acknowledge the fetched records is greater than the max.poll.interval.ms, the polling will be considered as failed and that particular batch will re-polled again from the Kafka topic.

Comment: It means, you suggest, I need to program slowing down myself and do not use auto commit, or?

Comment: Yes. Slow down the program for the intended wait time and use manual commit. But, I'm still not sure why you would want to reduce the performance of your consumer.

Comment: Manual commits are not really possible in Kafka Streams... Or is the question not targeted to Streams API?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Is max.poll.records applicable for kstream api?

Comment: Yes. Basically all consumer and producer configs are applicable.

Answer (score 7):

A KafkaConsumer (also the one that is internally used by `KafkaStreams` reads record as fast as possible.

The parameter you mention can have an impact on performance, but you cannot control the actual data rate. Also note, that `max.poll.records` only configures how many records `poll()` return, but it has no impact on client-broker communication. A `KafkaConsumer` can fetch more records when talking to the broker, and then return buffered messages on `poll()` as long as records are in the buffer (ie, for this case, `poll()` is a client-side operator that only ensures that you don't timeout via `max.poll.interval.ms`). Thus, you might be more interested in `fetch.max.bytes`, that determines the size of bytes fetches from the broker. If you reduce this parameter, the consumer is less efficient and thus throughput should decrease. (it's not recommended though).

Another way to configure throughput are quotas (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotas) It's a broker side configuration that allows you limit the amount of data a client can read and/or write.

The best thing to do in Kafka Streams (and also when using a plain KafkaConsumer) is to throttle calls to `poll()` manually. For Kafka Streams, you can add a `Thread.sleep()` into any UDF. If you don't want to piggyback this into an existing operator, you can just add an `foreach()` with ephemeral state (ie, a class member variable) to track the throughput and compute how much you need to sleep to throttle the throughput accordingly.

Comment: At the end (it is already in production software) I had implemented the last suggestion - message throttler :-). Thanks for confirmation and summary of ideas.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias J. Sax, so if use thread.sleep(1 sec) with max.poll.records=100, I can guarantee that the maximum consumption rate of the consumer per second =100, (at least what is returned from the local buffer to the consumer app poll loop). Is it safe to deduce that f returned records less than 100 then my arrival rate is less than 100. More generally what conclusion can be deduced on the arrival rate when the returned records are less than 100 with the above configuration.... how does the consumption rate correlates to the arrival rate if any? thanks

Comment: Having observed the sequence of variation of the consumer rate  dynamically, what event  indicates that the consumer  can not keep up with the arrival rate, is it the presence of lag even a few couple of message lags? any hint ?

Comment: If you use `sleep()` it would be executed for _every_ record. So you might want to use like 10ms to get to roughly 100 records per second. -- And yes, lag (or to be more precise, _growing_ lag), is an indicator that the consumer cannot keep up.

Answer (score 2):

In Kafka there is new concept of Kafka Quota.

All details are here [Kafka -> 4.9 Quotas](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotas)

Comment: ah! we met here :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like akka-stream-kafka (aka reactive-kafka) on the consumer side. akka-streams has nice throttling capabilities which will come in handy here:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/stream/stream-quickstart.html#time-based-processing